# Text file is not longer saved with ANSI in Windows Notepad

Tags: windows-10, notepad

When I save a text file in Windows Notepad by selecting ANSI as encoding in the save file dialog, the text file is not longer saved with ANSI but with UTF-8. Why is the text file not longer saved with ANSI? How do I solve the problem? How do I get the text file to be saved with ANSI?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem (Windows 10). This solved it for me:
Open Settings -> Time and Language -> Language
Click "Administrative language settings"
Click "Change system locale..."
*Un*check the checkbox "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"

After a restart, Notepad behaved nicely.